# Is this REST api correctly designed?

Tags: rest

I am working on a deployment system that needs some app deployed on a pool on either all or a subset of machines in the pool. To keep it simple, lets say I only have 3 requirements on the api.

1. deploy
2. cancel
3. status

I am now confused about designing the REST api calls for the above actions: Here is what I have in mind. If the payload is empty, I deploy on all the machines in the pool.

```
http://my-endpoint/api/{pool-name}/deploy

Payload:
{
    "machines" : [
        "machine-1.fqdn",
        "machine-2.fqdn",
        "machine-3.fqdn"
    ]
}
Response:
{
    "status": "OK",
    "jobId": "9999"
}
```

The client can then poll for the status or cancel the deployment based on the jobId:

```
http://my-endpoint/api/{pool-name}/status/{jobId}
http://my-endpoint/api/{pool-name}/cancel/{jobId}
```

Now, the jobId is unique across the entire deployment system so having {pool-name} in the api for "status" and "cancel" does not seem to be right. Is this a good design? I have read up a number of articles online that talk about mapping actions in REST and they have only helped in adding to my confusion. I do not have any CRUD as such in my application. I just want to make sure I am doing this the right way. Can someone please point out the flaws in the design? Any pointers will help.

Comment: I would remove the "/api" part in the url, but the rest looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

First, your responses don't allow for the possibility that some machines work and some machines don't. So your response probably needs to be an array, with  a status per attempted machines.

Second, this is not strictly restful, your are creating URLs that are effectively verbs. Pragmatically it will work, but to be RESTful you should be identifying your entities and using GET, PUT, POST and DELETE.

So here your entity could just be the Job.

```
PUT to /myendpoint/api/job
```

with a payload containing the poolname and the machine array. the response would be an array of status and job ids.

```
[ 
{
"status": "OK",
"jobId": "m1-9999"
},{
"status": "OK",
"jobId": "m2-9999"
},{
"status": "BAD",
"machine": "m3"
"reason": "xxx"
}
]
```

You the GET on the job id to get the status. The jobid is sufficient to identify which machine it's on.

```
GET myendpoint/api/job/m2-9999
```

and POST to the same URL with a payload of "cancel" to cancel the job.

Comment: +1, except that the semantics of PUT is not appropriate here — PUT should create a new resource at the URL being PUTted to. Use POST.

Comment: @djna Thank you very much. You put me on the right track. Regarding your observation on the status per machine, I agree. I should have mentioned that the deploy just creates a new job which is picked up by Quartz. All the details about the job execution are returned to the client in the status call.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy Yes, I will use a POST. I believe I do not need to expose PUT since there is nothing to change once a job has been created. It could only be cancelled or queried for status.

Comment: @Anton: I'm puzzled, we are creating a new Job resource, why is PUT not appropriate for that?

Comment: @djna The standard semantics of PUT is to create a resource at the URL specified in the request, i.e. PUT /jobs/12345 should create a new job with the id 12345, such that a subsequent GET /jobs/12345 would get the current state of the job object. However you usually don't want the callers to be able to specify a new job's id, instead you generate it yourself and return it to the caller. Ergo, the caller doesn't know the URL at which the new job will be available, so POST is appropriate. See sections 9.5 and 9.6 of the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5).

Answer (score 0):

For cancel and status, I would actually prefer following

`http://my-endpoint/api/{pool-name}/cancel/{job-id}`

My design would be to not take any action for empty request payload. This is to prevent non-serious users attacking API unnecessarily. I would expect a Payload, else throw an Error response back to them.

Again for successful Cancel/Status, would send back a response like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<request-result>
<http-code>200</http-code>
<description>REST Request is successfully processed</description>
<internal-error-info></internal-error-info>
<message>Job with {id} is processed successfully</message>
<requested-operation>Cancel</requested-operation>
<resource-name>JobName</resource-name>
<status>SUCCESSFUL</status>
</request-result>
```